# Prove that $\max(X,Y)$ is random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I need help with answering the following questions:

Given $X,Y$ random variables:

(1) prove that $\max(X,Y)$ is random variable

(2) suppose $X$ and $Y$ iid show that: $F_{\max(X,Y)}(t) = F_X(t)F_Y(t)$

(3) give example for $X$ and $Y$ that: $F_{\max(X,Y)}(t) = F_X(t)$

My thoughts:

(1) let's mark $\max(X,Y)$ as $Z$ for simplicity, $Z$ is a measurable function $Z:\Omega\rightarrow E\space$ , where $\space\Omega$ is the set of possible outcomes and $E$ is a measurable space. Is that enough to say that $\max(X,Y)$ is a random variable?

(2) I don't know where to start with.

(3) Each pair of CDFs which satisfy $F_X(t) \succ F_Y(t)$ will result $F_{\max(X,Y)}(t) = F_X(t)$

for example: $X\sim Unif[9,10],\space Y\sim Unif[5,6]$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{\max\{X,Y\} \leq a\}=\{X \leq a\} \cap \{Y \leq a\}$ which is measurable for each real number $a$. Hence $\max\{X,Y\}$ is a random variable.

$P(\{\max\{X,Y\} \leq t\})=P(X,\leq t, Y \leq t)=P(X\leq t)P(Y\leq t)=F_X(t)F_Y(t)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

For the last part take $Y=X$.

Comment: Thank you, can you please expand a bit the move from $P(X\leq t, Y\leq t)$ to $P(X\leq a)P(Y\leq a)$ why did $t$ changed to $a$? is it typo?

Comment: @AvivSham Sorry, there was a typo.

Comment: I have another question please why $\{\max\{X,Y\} \leq a\}=\{X \leq a\} \cap \{Y \leq a\}$ don't we want the $\cup$ between them? since we want the $max(X,Y)$ to be smaller then $a$?

Comment: Maximum of two numbers is less than or equal to $a$ iff both of them  are less than or equal to $a$. So $\max \{X,Y\} \leq a$ means $X\leq a$ **and** $Y\leq a$. @AvivSham

Comment: OMG I was confused with greater, my bad! Thank you very much :)